What is the meaning of "meanwhile" in this context?
I know the meaning of "meanwhile" is "while something else is happening" or "until something expected happens". But I just do not know how the above definition adds up in the following sentence:
"The storm is expected to move north today. Concerns are mounting MEANWHILE for a missing surfer." Can somebody explain what "meanwhile" means here in this sentence?
P/s: By the way in my question above, should the word "definition" in the phrase "But I just do not know how the above definition ..." be in singular or plural form since I put 2 meanings of the word "meanwhile" in the previous sentence? Thank you

"Meanwhile" is "while something else is happening", but also suggests that the new thing that is "meanwhile happening" is happening separately or in a different place to the first.
So here we have "The storm is moving north" (and away from the beach where the surfer is missing)  At the same time, at the beach, people are concerned about the missing surfer.
Now if we are to get picky, the first sentence only talks about expectations. So in a formal or literary style, we might avoid "meanwhile".  But this is meant to be an "off the cuff" comment by a newscaster.
If it helps, try mentally moving the word "meanwhile" before the word "Concerns".  It doesn't change the meaning and it makes it clearer how "meanwhile" is acting as a linking word between the two sentences.

Thank you. Its clearer to me now

"Meanwhile" is a word favoured by radio and TV journalists to connect disparate and otherwise unconnected events. It helps to make the broadcast flow. It is much seldom used in print journalism as the reader doesn't need those links.

The literal meaning of adverbial meanwhile is while something else is happening, as OP has correctly determined.
The sense until something expected happens carries the implication while we/you are waiting (for the expected thing to happen). Personally, I'd rather see that expressed as [in the] meantime. Here's a usage chart showing that most published writers agree with me...

Most items contributing to the above chart will be things like...

The person you want to see will be here in a few minutes...
... (1) Meanwhile, you can wait over there
... (2) In the meantime, you can wait over there

You'll sometimes see in the meanwhile, but that's become increasingly dated over the last century or two, so it's best avoided. And you'll sometimes see meantime used adverbially without preceding in the - but so far as I'm concerned, meantime is a noun, so it should be preceded by in the to make an adverbial element.
